# MYSQL select statement with non unique primary key

Tags: mysql, key, alter

## Cars

```
|Vin  |Make |Year|
|  1  |Honda|2009|
|  2  |Honda|2010|
|  3  |Honda|2009|
|  4  |Toyota|2009|
```

## Colors

```
|Color|Make |Vin|
| Red |Honda|1|
|Blue |Toyota|4|
|Pink |Honda|2|
```

## Financer

```
|Bank|Make |
| BOA |Honda|
| Cha |Toyota|
| PNC |Jeep|
```

## A query

```
SELECT
car.Vin,
colors.Color,
financer.Bank
from Car 
JOIN Colors ON car.vin = colors.vin
           AND car.make = colors.make
JOIN financer ON car.make = financer.make
WHERE car.make = 'Honda'
```

Trying to join these tables but getting more rows than expected.  My `financer` table above doesn't have a column that's unique.

Is there a way that I can do an ALTER TABLE to make a primary key unique by combining 2 columns?

Comment: A primary key must be unique by definition. You should post the results you get, and the results you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a step back from the RDBMS details, and consider what it means that your `financer` table has no unique column. What does that mean in the world of your application?

1. It might mean that a particular `Make` has more than one `Bank` that gives loans, in which case there's some kind of choice, or alternative, embedded in that table.
2. It might mean there are completely duplicated rows.

Here are examples of both circumstances.

```
|Bank |Make     |
| BOA |Honda    |
| TD  |Honda    |  1. more than one bank finances Honda
| Cha |Toyota   |
| PNC |Jeep     |
| PNC |Jeep     |  2. entirely duplicate row
```

This version of the `financer` table generates this result set (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/27705/2/0). It has, as you mention plenty of duplicates

```
| Vin | Color | Bank |
|-----|-------|------|
|   1 |   Red |  BOA |
|   2 |  Pink |  BOA |
|   1 |   Red |   TD |
|   2 |  Pink |   TD |
|   4 |  Blue |  Cha |
```

You can prevent the completely duplicated rows by creating a composite primary key, consisting of both columns. That probably makes sense in your application's world.

If you want a 1::1 relationship Make::Bank, you can put a primary key on Make. But I suspect that won't model your application's world correctly. (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/27705/5/0)

Maybe you want this query:

```
SELECT cars.Vin, cars.Make,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT colors.Color) Colors,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT financer.Bank) Banks
  from Cars 
  JOIN Colors ON cars.vin = colors.vin
             AND cars.make = colors.make
  JOIN financer ON cars.make = financer.make
 GROUP BY cars.Make, cars.vin
```

This combination of `GROUP_CONCAT()` and `GROUP BY` yields a list of matching colors, and a list of matching banks, for each car.

```
| Vin |   Make | Colors |  Banks |
|-----|--------|--------|--------|
|   1 |  Honda |    Red | TD,BOA |
|   2 |  Honda |   Pink | TD,BOA |
|   4 | Toyota |   Blue |    Cha |
```

As you can see, each of the Honda cars has a list of two banks.